# Trying to built a function that returns medians, keep getting "index a float not integer" errors

Tags: python-3.x, math, median

```
            def median(lst):
              sorted_lst=sorted(lst)
              if len(lst)%2==0:
                even_median=0.5*sum(sorted_lst[0.5*len(sorted_lst)]+
sorted_lst[(0.5*len(sorted_lst))-1])
                return even_median
              else:
                odd_median=sorted_lst[0.5*((len(sorted_lst))-1)]
                return odd_median
```

I've checked 5 times, the numbers are integers for sure, what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: 0.5 times anything is absolutely guaranteed to be a float.  It might be a float with an integral value, but that's not the same thing as an int.  Use `int(x)` to get a value that is valid for indexing, or use `len(x)/2` to do integer division and never involve floats at all.

Comment: @jasonharper "use `len(x)/2` to do integer division" doesn't work in Python3. Would need to use `//`.